# Return Action to an other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I would like to return an Action to an other Controller

Example: i have 2 controlers:

```
[Route("myurl"]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        if (...)
           {
              return Action2(); //working fine i will keep my route
           }
        else
           {
              return OtherController.Action3(); //Don't know how to do it here.
           }
    }
    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class OtherController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action3()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It's working if the Action is inside the same controller but wish to return the Action1 from HomeController to Action3 from OtherController.
I want to keep the same route (not a redirection to an other route).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out:

I need to return like that :

```
return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<OtherController>().Action3();
```

---

```
[Route("myurl"]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        if (...)
           {
              return Action2(); //working fine i will keep my route
           }
        else
           {
              return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<OtherController>().Action3();
           }
    }
    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using this **RedirectToAction**?

```
return RedirectToAction("ACTION_NAME", "CONTROLLER_NAME", new { area = "" });
```

Comment: Yes i tried that but it's doing a redirection, i wish to avoid that.

Comment: Try using this:

Comment: `return View("../CONTROLLER_NAME/ACTION_NAME");`

Comment: It will not call the OtherController, it will just display an other View()

Comment: So you want to call the "OtherController" including it's view but you want to keep the routing at "HomeController"?

Comment: If that's the case, then you can register a new route like for example:

Comment: `routes.MapRoute(
     "ROUTE_NAME",
     "Home/{ACTION_NAME}/{id}",
      new { controller = "OtherController", action="ACTION_NAME", id = ""});`

Comment: Here it will not call HomeController => Action1, http://monsite.com/myurl have to call HomeController => Action1 and return (not redirect) OtherController => Action3. In you reply we will go directly to OtherController => Action3. `+1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129007/discussion-between-philip-domingo-and-yanga).

Comment: I just found the answer, i need to returnlike that : `return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<OtherController>().Action3();`

Comment: Awesome. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");

Comment: Thank you but i want to avoid a redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the below method of controller class `protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName);` For your requirement the code inside the else block would look like `base.RedirectToAction("ACtion3","OtherController");`

Comment: I wish to avoid a redirection and keep my Route, it's working if a return to an action in the same controller.